# Derivative of the fundamental solution of the heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

Let $\Gamma$ be the fundamental solution of the heat equation in $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^n$, that is 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(t,x)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{4t}} \mbox{ per }x\in\mathbb{R}^n,t>0.
\end{equation}

In the book by Ladyzhenskaya,Solonnikov and Ural'tseva "Linear and Quasi-linear Equations of Parabolic Type" at page 274 is stated this inequality
\begin{equation}
|D_t^rD_x^s\Gamma(t,x)|\leq C_{r,s}t^{-\frac{n}{2}-r-\frac{s}{2}}e^{C\frac{-|x|^2}{t}}.
\end{equation}
It's correct?
The exponent of $t$ in the inequality won't be $-\frac{n}{2}-2r-s$ or I have made an  error in the computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Say, each differentiation w.r.t. $t$ adds $-1$ to the exponent of $t$.

Comment: But $D_t\Gamma(t,x)=(-\frac{C}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}+\frac{C'|x|^2}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}+2}})e^{-C''\frac{|x|^2}{t}}$ and $D_{x_i}\Gamma(t,x)=-\frac{Cx_i}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}}e^{-C'\frac{|x|^2}{t}}$. So it is not correct my exponent?

Comment: Note that there is $|x|$ in the numerator, which is absent in the rhs. 

For $a>0$ function $y^a e^{-y/2}$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$ and thus  $$y^a e^{-y}=y^a e^{-y/2}e^{-y/2}\le Me^{-y/2}$$ there. So $$\frac{|x|^a}{t^{a/2}} e^{-c |x|^2/t}\le M e^{-c |x|^2/(2t)}.$$